# Swift Add Image to UIImageView from User Tap

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview, uiimageview, uitapgesturerecognizer

I have a `ScrollView` with an `ImageView` inside.
Here a user can select a point on the image and it will print out the coordinates.

I'm also trying to add an image ("pin") to the tapped coordinate but am unsure how to...

```
// MARK: - Outlets
@IBOutlet weak var containerView: UIView!
@IBOutlet weak var scrollView: UIScrollView!
@IBOutlet weak var sharkImage: UIImageView!

// MARK: - View Did Load
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    scrollView.minimumZoomScale = 1.0
    scrollView.maximumZoomScale = 6.0

    scrollView.delegate = self

    let tapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(tapAction))

    self.sharkImage.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    self.sharkImage.addGestureRecognizer(tapGestureRecognizer)
}

// MARK: - Scroll View
func viewForZooming(in scrollView: UIScrollView) -> UIView? {
    return sharkImage
}

// MARK: - Functions
func tapAction(sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    // Get points for the UIImageView
    let touchPoint = sender.location(in: self.sharkImage)
    print(touchPoint)

    // Get points from the image itself
    let z1 = touchPoint.x * (sharkImage.image?.size.width)! / sharkImage.frame.width
    let z2 = touchPoint.y * (sharkImage.image?.size.height)! / sharkImage.frame.height
    print("Touched point (\(z1), \(z2)")

}
```

Comment: use `self.view.addSubview(your_img)`. and the `your_img.frame = CGRect(frame_here)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `tapAction`:

```
let pin = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: touchPoint.x - 20, y: touchPoint.y - 20, width: 40, height: 40))
pin.image = UIImage(named: "pin")
sharkImage.addSubview(pin)
```

So what I´m doing is adding a new `UIImageView` with the `x` and `y` from `touchPoint.x` and `touchPoint.y` into your current `sharkImage`.

Comment: Thanks Rashwan - it worked - the only downside is it adds the image below and to the right of the tap. It doesn't center the image on the users tap.

Comment: @pmanning, of course we want to center the image. Check the updated code. You basically set minus the width and height. Check it out.